# integral of a function minus its integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have encountered a problem in measure theory: Prove: If $X$ is a measure space with $\mu(X)=1$ and $0\leq f\leq a$ is measurable. Then $\int_X(f-\int_Xfd\mu)^2d\mu\leq \frac{a^2}{4}$.

I tried to partition $X$ into two measurable sets, where $E_1=\{x:f(x)\geq \int_Xfd\mu\}$ and $E_2=\{x:f(x)<\int_Xfd\mu\}$. But then this does not work since I have the square in the equation and I am not able to relate $\int_X(f-\int_Xfd\mu)^2d\mu\leq \frac{a^2}{4}$ with $\int_X|f-\int_Xfd\mu|d\mu\leq \frac{a}{2}$. Can you give any hint of how the $\frac{a^2}{4}$ comes into the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $(X,\mathcal F,\mu)$ defines a *probability* space under the circumstances, where $\mathcal F$ is the set of $\mu$ - measurable subsets of $X$.

Let $y :=\int_X fd\mu$.
Note that $\int_X (f -y)^2 = \int_X f^2d\mu - 2y\int_X fd\mu + y^2 = \int_X f^2 d\mu - y^2$.

Now, we want to show that $0 \leq f \leq a$, then the above difference is less than $\frac{a^2}{4}$.

Note that $y = E[f]$, so that the above formula is just the variance of $f$.

Let's use the [Bhatia-Davis inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhatia%E2%80%93Davis_inequality), which we are good doing, since we are on the real line, and $f$ is bounded.

This says that  Var$(f) \leq (M-y)(y - m)$, where $m \leq f \leq M$. Now, we have $M = a, m = 0$, so $Var(f) \leq y(a-y)$. The right side is maximised for $y = \frac a2$, and gives exactly $\frac {a^2}4$. Hence, the conclusion follows.

Note : A proof of the Bhatia-Davis inequality has been provided by @jvdillon below. I thank him.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without the use of Bhatia-Davis inequality? I can't see any easy proof of the inequality.

Comment: I am unsure, but I will think about it.  It is a very strong inequality.

Comment: Here is a proof of the Bhatia–Davis inequality.

Claim:
Let $X \in [m, M]$ be a bounded random variable with mean $\mu$. Then $\operatorname{Var}[X] \le (M - \mu)(\mu - m).$

Proof: 
Wlog assume $X \ge 0$, hence $m=0$. Then:
$(M - \mu)(\mu - m) - \mathbb{E}[(X - \mu)^2]
= {(M + m) \mu - \mu^2 - Mm} - (\mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mu^2)
= (M + m) \mu - Mm - \mathbb{E}[X^2]
= M \mu - \mathbb{E}[X^2]
\ge M \mu - \mathbb{E}[M X]
= M \mu - M \mu 
= 0 $

Comment: @jvdillon Thank you for the addition of the proof, I will link you in my answer.